# Problem with cocotb example code getting to work

Tags: cocotb

I got a few of the cocotb examples running, but not the most referenced to (endian_swapper).

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
make SIM=ghdl TOPLEVEL_LANG=vhdl

...

0.00ns CRITICAL cocotb.regression                         regression.py:137  in initialise                      Failed to import module test_endian_swapper_hal: 'return' with argument inside generator (test_endian_swapper_hal.py, line 67)
....


SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
     0.00ns ERROR    cocotb.gpi                                  gpi_embed.c:425  in embed_sim_init                  cocotb initialization failed - exiting
     0.00ns ERROR    cocotb.scheduler                            __init__.py:198  in _sim_event                      Failing test at simulator request before test run completion: Simulator shutdown prematurely
```

Comment: You're ending up using python 2.7 somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Does this suggestion help you?: https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/issues/1539#issuecomment-605706516

If you feel a bit more adventurous, install cocotb master where this is fixed (one minute ago :).

Comment: Eric says you are using Python 2.7 somehow. Setting ``PYTHON_BIN``should help. We are currently working on making sure such a mixup is not possible anymore,

Comment: I believe https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/pull/1574 will fix this